# Why does this not match my example?

Tags: regex

as I go through the regex101 quiz/lessons, I am supposed to match an IP address (without leading zeros).

Now the following

```
^[^0]+[0-9]+\\.[^0]+[0-9]+\\.[^0]+[0-9]+\\.[^0]+[0-9]+$
```

matches `23.34.7433.33`

but fails to match single digit numbers like 1.2.3.4

Why is this so, when my `+` is supposed to match "1 to infinite" times...?

Comment: You don't limit each number to three digits.

Comment: That would be my next step, once I get it working with just single digits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to check an IPv4, I suggest you this pattern:

```
^(?<nb>2(?>[0-4][0-9]|5[0-5])|1[0-9]{2}|[1-9]?[0-9])(?>\.\g<nb>){3}$
```

I have defined a named subpattern *nb* to make the pattern shorter, but if you prefer, you can rewrite all and replace `\g<nb>`:

```
^(?>2(?>[0-4][0-9]|5[0-5])|1[0-9]{2}|[1-9]?[0-9])(?>\.(?>2(?>[0-4][0-9]|5[0-5])|1[0-9]{2}|[1-9]?[0-9])){3}$
```

Numbers greater than 255 are not allowed.

pattern details:

The goal is to describe what is allowed:

1. numbers with 3 digits that begins with "2" can be followed by a digit in [0-4] and a digit in [0-9] OR by 5 and a digit in [0-5] because it can exceed 255.
2. numbers with 3 digits that begins with "1" can be followed by any two digits.
3. any number with 2 digits that doesn't begin with "0"
4. any number with 1 digit (zero included)

If I add one by one these rules, I obtain

1. `2(?>[0-4][0-9]|5[0-5])`
2. `2(?>[0-4][0-9]|5[0-5]) | 1[0-9]{2}`
3. `2(?>[0-4][0-9]|5[0-5]) | 1[0-9]{2} | [1-9][0-9]`
4. `2(?>[0-4][0-9]|5[0-5]) | 1[0-9]{2} | [1-9][0-9] | [0-9]`

Now I have a definition for allowed numbers. I can reduce a little the size of the pattern replacing 
`[1-9][0-9] | [0-9]` by `[1-9]?[0-9]`

Then you only have to add the dot repeat the subpattern four times: x.x.x.x

But since there is only three dots, I write the first number and I repeat 3 times a group that contains a dot and a number:

```
2(?>[0-4][0-9]|5[0-5])|1[0-9]{2}|[1-9]?[0-9]  # the first number
(?>\.2(?>[0-4][0-9]|5[0-5])|1[0-9]{2}|[1-9]?[0-9]){3} # the group repeated 3 times
```

To be sure that the string doesn't contain anything else that the IP I described, I add anchors for the *start of string* `^` and for the end of string `$`, then the string begins and ends with the IP.

To reduce the size of a pattern you can define a named group which allows to reuse the subpattern it contains,

Then you can rewrite the pattern like this:

```
^
(?<nb> 2(?>[0-4][0-9]|5[0-5])|1[0-9]{2}|[1-9]?[0-9] )  # named group definition
(?> \. \g<nb> ){3} # \g<nb> is the reference to the subpattern named nb
$
```

Comment: @dwilbank: I added a rewritten version.

Comment: Thanks! This is the golden formula that passes the quiz. Now it will be years before I understand all those atomic groups etc...

Comment: @dwilbank: I will add some explanations, it's easy.

Comment: Diving into it now. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You are in fact matching more than 2 digits for each number in the IP address because you have:

```
[^0]+[0-9]+
```

`[^0]+` matches at least one character, and `[0-9]+` matches at least 1 character. Both will match 'at least 2 characters' (characters being in scope of the character classes).

Also `23.34.7433.3` [doesn't match your regex](http://www.regex101.com/r/zI1xQ2) for the reason I stated above.

And you might try this regex for the purpose you stated:

```
^(?:[1-9][0-9]{0,2}\.){3}[1-9][0-9]{0,2}$
```

`[1-9][0-9]{0,2}` will match up to 3 digits, with a non leading `0`.

EDIT: You mentioned in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18666079/why-does-this-not-match-my-example#comment27490850_18666120) that `0.0.0.0` (single digit zeroes) are to be accepted as well. The modified regex from above would be:

```
^(?:(?:[1-9][0-9]{0,2}|0)\.){3}(?:[1-9][0-9]{0,2}|0)$
```

Comment: Thanks sirs. Will definitely study these. Need to step away for an hour though.

Comment: @dwilbank Take your time :) Regex does take some time to assimilate!

Answer (score 2):

`[0-9]+` should be `[0-9]*`

- `*` matches 0 or more.
- `+` matches 1 or more.

You already have the case `[^0]` <--- this actually wrong because it will match letters also.

besides that it will match the first character that's NOT zero then at least one number after that.

It should be written as

```
 [1-9][0-9]*
```

This essentially checks the first letter and sees if its a number that's between 1-9 then the next numbers(0 nums to infinite nums) after that is a number 0-9.

Then this will come out to.

```
^[1-9][0-9]*\.[1-9][0-9]*\.[1-9][0-9]*\.[1-9][0-9]*$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Edit live on Debuggex](http://www.debuggex.com/r/k-xe6mqXmVyQ5ghS)

cleaning it up.

```
^(?:[1-9][0-9]*\.){3}[1-9][0-9]*$
```

this should work...

```
^(?:[1-9][0-9]*\.|[0-9])(?:[1-9][0-9]*\.|[0-9])(?:[1-9][0-9]*\.|[0-9])(?:[1-9][0-9]*|[0-9])$
```

cleaned up.

```
^(?:(?:[1-9][0-9]*|0)\.){3}(?:[1-9][0-9]*|0)$
```

Comment: this one won't allow any single-digit zeros. Still, I've learned some things!

Comment: @dwilbank What do you mean? I thought you don't want to have any single digit zeros.

Comment: I don't want any leading zeros, but according to the quiz, 0.0.0.0 is supposed to match.

Comment: Thank you sir. Now I'm not going to ask for code to limit the numbers from 0 to 255... I will read this http://www.regular-expressions.info/numericranges.html for a while.

Comment: These two links will help you out on some of the harder stuff on REGEX /[Concepts](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)/ [Syntax](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refadv.html)

Answer (score 1):

Your regex would match `ABCDEFG999.FOOBSR888` etc, because `[^0]` is any character other than a zero, and bith character classes are required by the `+`.

I think you want this:

```
^[1-9]\d*(\\.[1-9]\d*){3}$
```

having replaced various verbose expressions with their equivalent, this is 4 groups of digits each starting with a non-zero.

Actually the problem is far more complicated, because your approach (once corrected) allows `999.999.999.999`, which is not a valid IP.

Comment: Yours will also allow leading `0`s in the IP. For instance, `0.1.1.1` will match because of what `?` does to `[1-9]`.

Answer (score 0):

It might be because you need at least two digits between two dots '.'

try using this pattern: `^[^0]+[0-9]*\.[^0]+[0-9]*\.[^0]+[0-9]*\.[^0]+[0-9]*$`

Comment: the asterisk allows alpha characters through, which would make me sad

Comment: then use this one: `^[1-9]+[0-9]*\.[1-9]+[0-9]*\.[1-9]+[0-9]*\.[1-9]+[0-9]*$`. Now alpha characters should not be allowed

Comment: @dwilbank that's not true; the asterisk is just a quantifier

Comment: the asterisks are misbehaving for me here on regex101 - http://img33.imageshack.us/img33/2050/3f65.jpg

Comment: that is because of [^0]. have you tried my second version: ^[1-9]+[0-9]*\.[1-9]+[0-9]*\.[1-9]+[0-9]*\.[1-9]+[0-9]*$. also i posted another answer that should be valid for ip addreses. Cheers.

Comment: yay - working! Except now it's not allowing 0.0.0.0, which is part of my quiz parameters.

Comment: @dwilbank try this `^(?:[1-9]+[0-9]*|0)\.(?:[1-9]+[0-9]*|0)\.(?:[1-9]+[0-9]*|0)\.(?:[1-9]+[0-9]*|0)$` the short version would be `^(?:(?:[1-9]+[0-9]*|0)\.){3}(?:[1-9]+[0-9]*|0)$`

Answer (score 0):

to match ip address you should use this pattern:
\b(?:\d{1,3}.){3}\d{1,3}\b

taken from here: 
http://www.regular-expressions.info/examples.html

Comment: This allows leading `0`s in the IP.

Comment: @Jerry on that page I mentioned the long answer that perfectly matches ip address is `\b(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\b` and this does not allow numbers with leading 0-es and greater than 255.

Comment: Are you 100% sure? If [those](http://www.regex101.com/r/jN2tJ5) aren't leading zeroes, I don't know what they are :)

Comment: @Jerry Apparently i failed the network test. This regex accepts anything between 0 to 255 including leading 0'es but no more than 3 digits per token. :(

Comment: Yup. Don't worry, it's not a big deal. It's good that you read articles on regularexpressions.info if you want to learn regex. Also, try to test the regex you get or create as thoroughly as you can. There're many great regex testing sites out there to help you! I've linked one of my favourite already :P